# Call Elastic search from shell script for indexing pdf document

Tags: unix, elasticsearch

I installed elasticsearch 5.0.1 and corresponding ingest attachment. Tried indexing pdf document from shell script as below

```
#!/bin/ksh  
var=$(base64 file_name.pdf)

var1=$(curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_index4/my_type/my_id?pipeline=attachment&pretty' -d' { "data" : $var }')
echo $var1
```

---

```
I got error as 
{ "error" : { "root_cause" : [ { "type" : "exception", "reason" : 
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ElasticsearchParseException[Error parsing document in field 
[data]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Illegal base64 character 24];",
 "header" : { "processor_type" : "attachment" } } ]...
```

Can anyone please help on resolving the above issue ... Not sure whether I am passing invalid base64 character ?

Please note that when I pass like this, It works !

```
var1=$(curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_index4/my_type/my_id?pipeline=attachment&pretty'
-d' { "data" : "e1xydGYxXGFuc2kNCkxvcmVtIGlwc3VtIGRvbG9yIHNpdCBhbWV0DQpccGFyIH0=" }')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the issue has to shell not expanding the variables within single-quotes, you need to double-quote to expand it. i.e.

change `-d' { "data" : $var }'`

to

```
-d '{"data" : "'"$(base64 file_name.pdf)"'"}'
```

directly to pass the `base64` stream.

(or)

```
-d '{"data" : "'"$var"'"}'
```

More about quoting and variables in `ksh` [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=99035&seqNum=6).