# 'Illegal base64 character' exception when indexing pdf in elasticsearch from shell script

Tags: unix, elasticsearch

I installed elasicsearch 5.0.1 with ingest attachment and tried indexing pdf in elasticsearch from shell script using below command

```
#!/bin/ksh  
var=$(base64 sample.pdf | perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/g')
var1=$(curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_index5/my_type/my_id?pipeline=attachment&pretty' -d' { "data" : "'$var'" }')
echo $var1
```

Got an error as

```
{ "error" : { "root_cause" : [ { "type" : "exception", "reason" : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ElasticsearchParseException[Error parsing document in field [data]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Illegal base64 character a];", "header" : { "processor_type" : "attachment" } } ]
```

Can anyone please help resolving the above error

Comment: It seems, you're not applying the solution to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716670/call-elastic-search-from-shell-script-for-indexing-pdf-document) correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I applied that solution too (ie) passed as                    " ' " $var " ' " .. Still same error ...

Answer (score 0):

Rectified the error. 
Cause for this error is, In the base64 encoded content \n was present which caused the "Illegal format exception".
As a solution, When tried like below it worked

```
var=$(base64 sample.pdf | perl -pe 's/\n//g')
```